# Calling SSJS from Java?

Tags: java, serverside-javascript, xpages

I have created an xPages application which uses a lot of server side javascript code functions located in a server side javascript library.

Now I have some java code located in the java design element which I would like to use to call the javascript functions.

I do understand that it is not logical to call javascript from java, but I guess that all server side javascript is compiled to java, so I was thinking that it might be possible to get a handle to the compiled java class that was generated.

any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a value binding,

```
ValueBinding vb = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createValueBinding("#{javascript:getData()}");
System.out.println(vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).toString());
```

This would call the `getData()` method from your SSJS library.