# How to call ad hoc SSJS from a Java Bean

Tags: xpages, serverside-javascript

I need to call ssjs from a java bean similar to this [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099093/calling-ssjs-from-java). The issue is that the code I need to execute comes from a configuration document, and may look like:

```
getComponent("xxx").getValue();
```

I have built a version that does :

```
String compute = doc.getItemValueString("SSJSStuff");
String valueExpr = "#{javascript:" + compute + "}";
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application app = fc.getApplication();
ValueBinding vb = app.createValueBinding(valueExpr);
String vreslt = vb.getValue(fc).toString();
```

but I get `"Exception in xxx: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression"`

I think I am close, but I do not see over the hill.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities for this:

1. The variable *compute* is empty
2. *compute* contains illegal chars
3. The code inside *compute* is malformed / has no correct syntax
4. No object is returned in your SSJS code:

   If your SSJS code does not return something, *vb.getValue(fc)* returns *null*. A *toString()* will fail. To prevent this, you should cast your returning object explicitly:

   ```
   vreslt = (String) vb.getValue(fc);
   ```

Hope this helps

Sven

**EDIT**:
After re-reading your post, I saw that you want to do a *getComponent* in your dynamic SSJS Code. This won't work with a value binding added to the *javax.faces.application.Application*. For this, you have to use the *com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl* object instead:

```
String valueExpr = "#{javascript:" + compute + "}";
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionEvaluatorImpl evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluatorImpl( fc );
ValueBinding vb = evaluator.createValueBinding( fc.getViewRoot(), valueExpr, null, null);
vreslt = (String) vb.getValue(fc);
```

Comment: The answer is #4 - No object was being returned because the component was not available at that point in the XSP life cycle. I worked around that by passing the NotesDocument from the dataSource into the Java Bean method so I could go against the actual Notes Fields. I am going to look more into that ExpressionEvaluatorImpl though as it has promise for other parts of this project. /Newbs

Comment: Is there a way to inject an object to SSJS evaluation like `put(key, object)` in javax.script.ScriptEngine? I would like to evaluate the same script against all documents in Java document collection.

Comment: I ended up using javax.script.ScriptEngine and adding my Domino objects there which works fine. I'm evaluating an SSJS string which has "doc.getItemValue(..". I need to add the "doc" Object from Java to be included in the evaluation.