# Java equivalent of getComponent() in SSJS

Tags: java, xpages

I know that we can access the XPages global objects like this in Java

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
...
...
```

But I am unable to find any equivalent for using `getComponent()` is Java. Is there any class or method in Java which is similar to `getComponent()` in SSJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be easiest by evaluating SSJS in Java. Code from Sven:

```
String valueExpr = "#{javascript: getComponent('xxx').getValue();}";
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionEvaluatorImpl evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluatorImpl( fc );
ValueBinding vb = evaluator.createValueBinding( fc.getViewRoot(), valueExpr, null, null);
vreslt = (String) vb.getValue(fc);
```

[How to call ad hoc SSJS from a Java Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324445/how-to-call-ad-hoc-ssjs-from-a-java-bean)

Here is pure Java solution by Karsten Lehmann:

```
/** 
 * Finds an UIComponent by its component identifier in the current 
 * component tree. 
 * 
 * @param compId the component identifier to search for 
 * @return found UIComponent or null 
 * 
 * @throws NullPointerException if <code>compId</code> is null 
 */ 
public static UIComponent findComponent(String compId) { 
    return findComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot(), compId); 
} 

/** 
 * Finds an UIComponent by its component identifier in the component tree 
 * below the specified <code>topComponent</code> top component. 
 * 
 * @param topComponent first component to be checked 
 * @param compId the component identifier to search for 
 * @return found UIComponent or null 
 * 
 * @throws NullPointerException if <code>compId</code> is null 
 */ 
public static UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent topComponent, String compId) { 
    if (compId==null) 
        throw new NullPointerException("Component identifier cannot be null"); 

    if (compId.equals(topComponent.getId())) 
        return topComponent; 

    if (topComponent.getChildCount()>0) { 
        List childComponents=topComponent.getChildren(); 

        for (UIComponent currChildComponent : childComponents) { 
            UIComponent foundComponent=findComponent(currChildComponent, compId); 
            if (foundComponent!=null) 
                return foundComponent; 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/18.07.2009191738KLENAL.htm

Comment: There is a different behaviour  between Karsten's code and the *getCompenent* method in SSJS: While Karsten's code searches a component down from the top component, does the 'getComponent* method in SSJS perform a search from the current component upwards. This might result in different results. I am not sure what will happen if the method is used in a facet.

Comment: I would take the option of evaluating SSJS in Java as it is better and does the job in few lines of code. Thanks Paul!

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: I am using `getComponent` equivalent in the `querySaveDocument` event of the XPage and evaluating SSJS in Java option by Paul works in that scenario. Probably using it some field might yield different results. Haven't tried it though. Thanks the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In the Group extension of the Extension Library there is a query package that contains the  XspQuery class and some filters. This class was intended to function like dojo.query to give you many different ways to find a component, not just by the id but also things like Component Class, Client ID, Server ID, etc. Here's an example of using the server ID to locate a component:

```
XspQuery query = new XspQuery();
query.byId("someId");
List<UIComponent> componentList = query.locate();
```

You can find it here: https://svn-166.openntf.org/svn/xpages/extlib/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.group/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/query/

The Group extension was never distributed with the extension library, but was in the svn repository and to get it you had to go through the OpenNTF svn server.

Comment: How can I install Group extension in my Lotus Notes?

Comment: Unfortunately you would have to go through the OpenNTF SVN Server to get the entire plugin. Or if all you want is the XspQuery class, you can get it from the XBlog template (http://xblog.openntf.org or http://bitbucket.org/kstrickland/xblog). I'm also working to get the good parts of the group plugin into the OpenNTF Extension Library by Tim Tripcony (as opposed to the IBM Extension Library). Most of the components there have already been added to the IBM ExtLib but XspQuery never was added back into the product.

Comment: Thanks! I would look into that :)